# Рандомное перемешивание массива

Tags: java, массивы, случайные-числа, arraylist

Есть массив, в котором содержатся 4 элемента, как можно рандомно перемешать эти элементы, т. е. например, первый элемент стал третьим, второй четвертым и т. д. И так каждый раз по-разному.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Если вы не сильно задумываетесь о криптографической стойскости то

```
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Comment: От себя добавлю, что, учитывая особенности метода `Arrays.asList(arr)`, перемешать исходный массив arr[] можно таким образом:

`Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr))`

**Внимание!** не подходит для массивов примитивных типов (int[] и проч.).

Comment: Я бы сказал, что это особенность метода Collections.shuffle()

Answer (score 0):

Пример использования побочных эффектов от многопоточности:

```java
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

```java
Arrays.stream(arr).parallel()
        .mapToObj(i -> i + " ")
        .forEach(System.out::print); // 4 5 2 3 1
```

```java
Arrays.stream(arr).parallel()
        .mapToObj(i -> i + " ")
        .forEach(System.out::print); // 3 2 1 4 5
```

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Вывод будет всякий раз разным, при этом сам массив останется прежним.