# как перемешать данные в массиве типа Int

Tags: java, массивы

```
class learn_project1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    learn_project1 e = new learn_project1();
    e.run();
    fixedarray();
    randomdelete();
    randomizer();
    }
public static int size;
public static int i;
public static int [] arrayResult;

public static void run (){

}

public static void fixedarray() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);//объявляем сканнер

    System.out.println("Введите размера массива. Число должно быть не менее 10");
    size = input.nextInt(); // вводим размер массива
    int[] array = new int[size]; // объявление масссива - ты объявил массив в методе main. в других методах этот маммив не виден.понял? да
    /*проверка введенного размера массива*/
    if (size < 10) {
        System.out.println("Введенное число меньше 10. Выполнение программы далее невозможно.");// можно сделать повторение ввода- аля рестарта
        return;
    }
    if (size > 10) {
        System.out.println("Вводим данные в массив");
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            array[i] = i + 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Введенные элементы массива:");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
    } // Выводим на экран, полученный массив
}
public static void randomdelete(){
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int randomValue = rnd.nextInt(size - 1) + 1;//здесь все норм
    System.out.println("Рандомное число: " + randomValue);
    int[] arrayResult = new int[size - 1];
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if ((i + 1) != randomValue) {
            arrayResult[j] = i + 1;
            j++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + arrayResult[i]);
    }
}
public static void randomizer() {
    arrayResult[i]// применить функцию
}

}
// проверка что ввеенное значение это именно целое число больше 10
// заполение массива
// получение рандомного числа, которое находится в диапазоне заполненных 
чисел. обратить внимание на граничащие числа. напр. если массив заполнен 
числами от 1 до 10, то рандомайзер не должен выдавать 0 или 11 и далее
// удаление из массива полученного рандомного числа
// перемешивание массива
// вычисление удаленного рандомного числа
```

Comment: Например, с помощью swap и Random#next(arrayResult.length) в цикле.

Comment: Миллионом способов, нужно уточнить, что Вам нужно

Comment: Что именно Вам надо сделать? Если имеется в виду заполнение массива случайными числами, то вот [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/434707/240709)!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540464/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0 эта ссылка не содержит ответа. Напротив, там указано, что метод не подходит для примитивов. А тут именно массив примитивов надо перемешать.

Comment: ребята, есть готовый массив- уже, с удаленными числами- его нужно перемешать. те, методы, которые вы мне предложили - не совсем мне подходят. жду ответа. спасибо.